# Kibana keeps some fields unindexed

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

So I have an index in elasticsearch, and I want to search and visualize the index with Kibana. But several fields are not indexed by Kibana, and have this bubble:
`This field is not indexed thus unavailable for visualization and search`.
This is a snippet of one of the fields that is not indexed by Kibana:

```
"_event_name" : {
    "type" : "string"
},
```

I tried to enter Kibana's index settings and click "Reload field list", but it doesn't help.

Does anyone knows what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, [Kibana doesn't index fields that start with underscore](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2551).

Comment: This seems to be wrong, since _id and _index are both searchable.

Answer (score 0):

The fields might not be [indexed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2) as mentioned [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/this-field-is-not-indexed-thus-unavailable-for-visualization-and-search/33374/2?u=deb).

Comment: The post says "You need to make it an indexed field, which will mean changing your mappings and then reindexing the data.". But it doesn't say changing your mapping to *what*? How should I change my mapping to make the field indexed?

Comment: In my first link refer the section [Updating a mapping]( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#updating-a-mapping)

Comment: Refer the first link in my answer you have to set the index value of your field to either `analyzed` or `non_analyzed`

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading the data into Elasticsearch?  Logstash?  A Beat?  curl?  Please describe that and if you can include your config file that would be good.

You can look at your mapping in your browser with something like this;

```
http://localhost:9200/logstash-2016.07.20/_mapping?pretty
```

(change the host and index name)